# How best to organise data that is dependent on a field in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-structures, graphql

I am using Postgresql with graphql to deal with some data for posts on a website. The posts are slightly complex and I am just not sure what the best way to organise the data would be. The reason for this is because the Posts can be of different types, and as a result the data structures for the different types would vary. For example I have a text type and a video type where the video type would need a url, thumbnail and a description and the text would just need a description. I'm not sure what the best way to go about organising the data would be.

Would it be possible to somehow link multiple tables like below? So in other words would it be possible to query and get the right data depending on the ItemID in the posts table and then pull it out from the corresponding table.

The table of posts would look like:

```
|-----------|----------|----------|----------|
|    ID     |   Type   |   Title  |  ItemID  |
|-----------|----------|----------|----------|
|    1      |   Text   |  My text |  1234    |
|-----------|----------|----------|----------|
|    2      |   Video  |   A vid  |  3456    |
|-----------|----------|----------|----------|
```

The Video table would look like

```
|-----------|----------|----------|----------|
|    ID     |   Desc   |   URL.   | Thumbnail|
|-----------|----------|----------|----------|
|    3456   |   ....   |   ....   |  ....    |
|-----------|----------|----------|----------|
```

The Text table would look like

```
|-----------|----------|
|    ID     |   Desc   |
|-----------|----------|
|    1234   |   ....   |
```

The other way I can think of is just having a single table for the posts and just have the data as not required and have the possibility of all the fields. I will then just organise it in the front end as required.

Any thoughts or recommendation on how to best deal with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with your data model, except that I would use two different columns instead of `itemid`. Each of them has a foreign key, one to the video table and one to the text table. A check constraint makes sure that only one of them `IS NOT NULL` and that `type` matches, something like

```
CHECK (type = 'text' AND text_id IS NOT NULL AND video_id IS NULL OR
       type = 'video' AND text_id IS NULL AND video_id IS NOT NULL)
```

This way you can have foreign keys between the tables, which is essential for data integrity.

Comment: I see! That works really well. Do you by any chance know what the syntax would be to check if the type matches? Would it be just a condition for each where you would check with an `and` condition combination like below:
`CHECK (VideoIdentifier IS NOT NULL AND type IS 'video')` for video,
`CHECK (TextIdentifier IS NOT NULL AND type IS 'text')` for text

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about your design, but then I don't know the total spec.
You're going to have to use some code alongside your database design. To start with, a web page table, I'm also presuming your website has more than one page with posts.

WEBPAGE Table: WebPageID (PK), WebPageDesc

Then, we add a table for posts, for each webpage.
This assigns an ID to each post.

POST Table: PostID (PK), WebPageID (FK)

If you only have one page, then you obvs don't need the WEBPAGE table and you can alter the POST table to; just POST Table: PostID (PK)

Then, as you've worked out, a table to store all video posts, and another for text.

VIDEOPOSTS Table: VideoPostID (PK), VideoDesc, VideoURL

TEXTPOSTS Table: TextPostID (PK), TextDesc

Now you just need a couple of tables to link the different types of posts back to the webpage. Composite primary key in both, saves the need for an ID column.

POSTSVIDEOPOSTS Table: PostID (PK) (FK to post table), VideoPostID (PK) (FK to videoposts table)

POSTSTEXTPOSTS Table: PostID (PK) (FK to post table), TextPostID (FK) (FK to textposts table)

Further thinking:

You can add a deleted flag next to each post, to decided whether or not they should be included in the web page output or not, depending whether a user can delete posts or not.

With the above design, it's going to be difficult to sort the posts into the correct order, as you are retrieving them from two separate tables. This design is normalised tho, I think.

I'm just not sure it's 100% correct. I'd need to see more of the spec to be able to design it better. Perhaps if there is a datetime the post was made, that would make sorting easier?

But then I'm not 100% confident the original design in your original post using a Type column in the post table is correct either...

Does the design need to be normalised?

Happy for the above to be criticised by others, I'm pretty sure it needs further work!

Answer (score 0):

Your attempted check is on the right track, but not quite. First off the structure "type IS 'video'" is invalid. Null values are checked with IS, but other values are checked with [comparison operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-comparison.html). Secondly, as Laurenze indicates, you must ensure that one and only one of the foreign key identifiers is null. With these conditions we get:

```
check (    (   (vedioidentifier is null and textidentifier is not null)
            or (vedioidentifier is not null and textidentifier is null)
           )
       and (   (type = 'video' and vedioidentifier is not null)
            or (type = 'text' and textidentifier is not null)
           )
      )
```

**Caution against CamelCase:** Postgres maintains CamelCase names for identifies only if they are also enclosed in double quotes ("). If you do so you most ALWAYS use double quotes for every reference. If not double quoted Postgres folds all identifiers to lower case. A much better approach is to use snake_case identifier names.